# Action Script 3 - Capture current playing sound and continuously write to server (for streaming)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, streaming

Basically as my flash program is running I would like it to take the current sounds playing and continuously write that stream to a server. So that another user can then listen to that stream. Basically like a web radio.

This is my naive guess of what to do.

```
client:
  capture current playing sounds
  convert to mp3
  write to mp3 file on server

other client:
  load that mp3 and play the streaming song
```

Anyone familiar with a solution to this? code examples? I have looked but just don't know enough about Action Script 3 to get anywhere far :/

Note: I am not capturing sound from a microphone, but the current playing sound. (I have written a simple waveform analyzer that reacted to the playing sounds)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amy Mentioned in a comment:
[Adobe Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-server-family.html?sdid=EDXSC&skwcid=TC%7C22193%7Cadobe%20flash%20media%20server%7C%7CS%7Cb%7C14152144342)

As well I also found another (cheaper) solution:
[Wowza](http://www.wowza.com)